# How updating pageAnime value with useState in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, fetch-api

function DetailAnime() {

```
const [detailAnime, setDetailAnime] = useState([]);
const [pageAnime, setPageAnime] = useState(1);

const { id } = useParams([]);

const { pathname } = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
    if(pathname.split('/').includes('popular')){
        getAnimePopular(pageAnime).then((res) => {
            setDetailAnime(res)
        })
    } else {
        getAnimeList(pageAnime).then((res) => {
            setDetailAnime(res)
            console.log(res)
        }); 
    } 
}, [pathname, pageAnime]);
```

I have issue to updating page when i click detailAnime, could you help me?

//api url
const apiUrl = 'https://api.jikan.moe/v4/';

export const getAnimeList = async (page) => {
const anime = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/anime?page=${page}`);
return anime.data.data;
}

Comment: Hi @adrianusyoga_ welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please share what issue you are getting ? i mean if you are getting any error message please share or update it in your question. It will really helpful to us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As far you have address your question, It looks like the issue is in your function `getAnimeList` where you have passing the url incorrectly, having spaces and missing backtick(``).

```js
// your api url
const apiUrl = 'https://api.jikan.moe/v4/';

export const getAnimeList = async (page) => { 
    const anime = await axios.get(`${ apiUrl }anime?page=${ page }`); 
    return anime.data.data; 
}
```